# Do messages get deleted from the queue after a read operation in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, apache-nifi

I am using Nifi to get data from IBM MQ. It is working fine. My question is once the message is read from an MQ queue, does it get deleted from the queue? How to just read messages from the queue without deleting them from the queue?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is once the message is read from an MQ queue, does it get
>   deleted from the queue?

Yes, that is the default behavior.

> How to just read messages from the queue without deleting them from
>   the queue?

You use the option: MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST followed by MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT on the MQGET API calls.

You can also open the queue for browse only. i.e. MQOO_BROWSE option for MQOPEN API call.

Comment: can i use this in MQ explorer?

Comment: @SerakShiferaw that doesn't make any sense.  The question was about programming.  You don't program MQ Explorer and MQ Explorer is coded to browse messages when the user clicks the 'Browse Messages' option.

Comment: Agree with @Roger. The OP said "read" by which it should be safe to assume this is a "get" operation, and indeed that's something you would do in a program. "get" and "put" are probably the most basic things one does with a queue like MQ

Answer (score -2):

It sounds as if you would like to use a "publish/subscribe" model rather than a "point-to-point" model.

From [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html):

> Topics In JMS a Topic implements publish and subscribe semantics. When
>   you publish a message it goes to all the subscribers who are
>   interested - so zero to many subscribers will receive a copy of the
>   message. Only subscribers who had an active subscription at the time
>   the broker receives the message will get a copy of the message.
>
> Queues A JMS Queue implements load balancer semantics. A single
>   message will be received by exactly one consumer. If there are no
>   consumers available at the time the message is sent it will be kept
>   until a consumer is available that can process the message. If a
>   consumer receives a message and does not acknowledge it before closing
>   then the message will be redelivered to another consumer. A queue can
>   have many consumers with messages load balanced across the available
>   consumers.

If you have a queue, when a consumer *consumes* that message, it is removed from the queue so that the next consumer consumes the next message. With a topic, multiple consumers can be subscribed to that topic and retrieve the same message without being exclusive.

If neither of these work for you, I'm not sure what semantics you're looking for -- a "queue" which doesn't delete the message when it is consumed will never let a consumer access any but the first message.

Comment: His question is about IBM MQ and not Apache MQ.